# How to implement a new system call that returns 2*(integer passed) in linux 4.19.20?

Tags: linux, operating-system, system, system-calls

All the online tutorials are for the system calls that do not return anything. I want a system call that prints twice the argument passed in printk.

Someone please provide a step by step approach.

Thank you for giving your time!

Comment: Take a look at this: [Link that might help](https://medium.com/anubhav-shrimal/adding-a-hello-world-system-call-to-linux-kernel-dad32875872). And this is far too broad of a question to ask on SO, please take a look at the guidelines and Googling a thing never hurts :)

Comment: NO @PradyumanDixit it did not work!! I have googled a lot before asking this and the link that you sent has the instructions for kernel 4.13 which is way old and all the directories and instructions have changed so far .

Comment: It's understandable, but SO is not really a place to ask for tutorials or step by step working, the question might get downvoted or deleted, at a later point. You may start things out yourself and ask a specific question related to the problem you get stuck at.